# jQuery html change color

Tags: javascript, jquery

currently I have made it working. But there is another thing I want to add something like Color. From red to green. The following code are below.

```
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var password = $("#textpwd").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#textcfmpwd").val();

    if (password != confirmPassword)
        $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords do not match!");
    else
        $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords match.");
}
```

How to make "Passwords do not match!" in red color whereas "Passwords match" in green color?

Comment: css is fine place to start

Comment: why dont you google `jquery css`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var password = $("#textpwd").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#textcfmpwd").val();

    if (password != confirmPassword)
        $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords do not match!").css('color', 'red');
    else
        $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords match.").css('color', 'green');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (password != confirmPassword)
{
    $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords do not match!");
    $("#pwdWarning").css("color","red");
}
else
{
    $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords match.");
    $("#pwdWarning").css("color","green");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.css()` like this:

```
if (password != confirmPassword)
    $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords do not match!").css("color", "red"); // can use background-color too.
else
    $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords match.").css("color","green");// can use background-color too.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the css class to messages

```
if (password != confirmPassword)
        $("#pwdWarning").html("<span class='error'>Passwords do not match!</span>");
    else
        $("#pwdWarning").html("<span class='success'>Passwords match.</span>");
```

And add css to these classes in css file

```
.error{
color:red
}
.success{
color:green}
```

Comment: That's too repetitive. He should be able to assume that ONE condition is true out of the gate (match or not). Then adjust at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to add a class with the appropriate CSS if you don't want to add it inline.

JS:

```
if (password != confirmPassword)
    $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords do not match!").addClass('red-text');
else
    $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords match.").addClass('green-text');
```

CSS:

```
.red-text {color: red;}
.green-text {color: green;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.css()` to set background color, see below code

```
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var password = $("#textpwd").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#textcfmpwd").val();

    if (password != confirmPassword)
     {
        $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords do not match!");
        $("#pwdWarning").css('background-color','red');
     }
    else
     {
        $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords match.");
        $("#pwdWarning").css('background-color','green');
     }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yv78yr2c/1/)**

OR you can use CSS classess to add background color, see below code

CSS

```
.red{background-color:red;}
.green{background-color:green;}
```

jQuery

```
function checkPasswordMatch() {
        var password = $("#textpwd").val();
        var confirmPassword = $("#textcfmpwd").val();

        if (password != confirmPassword)
         {
            $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords do not match!");
            $("#pwdWarning").addClass('red').removeClass('green');
         }
        else
         {
            $("#pwdWarning").html("Passwords match.");
            $("#pwdWarning").addClass('green').removeClass('red');
         }
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yv78yr2c/2/)**

Comment: any console error? can you share a jsfiddle link with your problem statement.